# How to create plans if they don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I want to create subscription plans in stripe programatically, and I want to be able to run this many times so if the plans exist it should just ignore it.

I noticed if I try and retrieve a plan it throws an exception if it doesn't exist:

```
plan1 = Strie::Plan.retrieve("abcd123")
>>Stripe::InvalidRequestError: No such plan: abcd123
```

I create a plan using:

```
Stripe::Plan.create(.....)
```

I have a plans model that has all my plans, so I ideally want to do this:

```
Plan.all.each do |plan|
  # create stripe plan here if it doesn't exist
end
```

What is the best way to handle this exception if the plan exists in stripe already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://stripe.com/docs/api#error_handling

If you attempt to create a plan with an id that already exists, the request will fail and Stripe will throw an invalid request error. You should be able to wrap your plan creation call to account for errors. A barebones example:

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xxxyyyzzz"

MyPlans.each do |plan|
    # try to create a plan
    begin 
        my_plan = Stripe::Plan.create(
          :amount => plan.amount,
          :interval => "month",
          :name => plan.name,
          :currency => "usd",
          :id => plan.id 
        )
        puts my_plan
    # catch any invalid request errors
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
        puts e.json_body[:error]
    end
end
```